# Flex item shrinks and hides its content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a flexbox that distributes space equally amongst its 2 children. The issue I encountered is that after I minimize the screen, the content of the first child is becoming hidden.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/jo6dj8ne/

[Gif showing the problem](https://image.ibb.co/j70kcH/Peek_2018_04_04_14_51.gif)

I'd like the content of the `info-section` div to always be visible, but the `map-section` div to shrink and the scrollbar to appear.

```
<div class="contact-container">
  <div class="info-section">
    ... some content (info-section is also a flexbox)
  </div>
  <div class="map-section"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it was totally unclear. I edited my question.

Comment: Did you change the Fiddle ...it doesn't look the same? I suspect that uour demo does not show the real issue. My best *guess* is that the map secton needs some proper content.

Comment: It's updated. The map section content is irrelevant and doesn't change the behaviour as far as I'm concerned. You can see the gif I attached to the question. It clearly shows that the info-section gets hidden/minimized. I don't want it to shrink that much it hides the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was setting [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to `1`, which was equivalent to setting it to `1 1 0`. At the time I was not familiar with [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow), [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) and [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) CSS properties, that's why I was having trouble making it work.

After setting [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) of `info-section` to `1 0 auto` it no longer shrinks and its initial size is equal to the size of its content.

Working example [here](https://codepen.io/radzak/pen/PRgQjQ).

Answer (score 0):

Just give `overflow: auto;` to `.info-section`
try this code:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.contact-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.contact-container .info-section {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
}
.contact-container .info-section .social {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
  margin-top: var(--padding-large);
}
.contact-container .map-section {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-container">
  <div class="info-section">
    <div class="heading">Heading</div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorizzle ipsum dolizzle stuff amizzle, shizznit adipiscing elit. Nullizzle sapien velizzle, mofo volutpizzle, suscipit quis, gravida bizzle.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="social">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/smashicons.jpg" width="40px">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/256/home-icon.png" width="40px">
      <img src="http://freedesignfile.com/upload/2017/04/Summer-holiday-vector-icon.jpg" width="40px">
      <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png" width="40px">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="map-section">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't work at all. Notice that part of the info-section gets hidden. Besides that, I wanted the info-section not to shrink more than the size of its children.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `min-height: 300px;` to `.info-section`. This will force the container to always have at least 300px of height. If it's bigger than that, it will scroll.

Complete CSS code:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.contact-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;

  .info-section {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 300px;
    .social {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
      grid-gap: 1em;
      margin-top: var(--padding-large);
    }
  }

  .map-section {
    background-color: blue;
    min-height: 200px;
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```